# Alternating Background Color Grid Rows not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement alternating background Color on my Rows.
I have an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemTemplate` in which I use `Triggers` on the `Style` Property of the `Border`.
But I end up with all `RoyalBlue` Rows instead of alternating with `Red`.
Can somene assist? Thank you very much!

```
<Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" >
      <Grid>
         <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Width="Auto">
            <Border.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <Grid >
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid >
         </Border>
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources> 

<ScrollViewer >
   <StackPanel  >
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myElements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" AlternationCount="2"/>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Mayby [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) helps you. They use a `Setter` and `Converter` instead of a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` will be set against direct child of `ItemsControl` panel (`ContentPresenter`) so you need to use `DataTrigger` with `RelativeSource` binding and because it's an attached property you need to put in brackets like `Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```